# How do I configure Thunderbird to locally remap the label-folder in an G-Mail IMAP account?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird, imap, label

I'm using G-Mail and Thunderbird together for an imap account.  One of the limitations of G-Mail is that there's no concept of nested labels - which is fine when I'm using the account through the web interface but when I'm using Thunderbird I would like a bit more organization.

Is there a way for Thunderbird to locally remap an imap folder's path?  For example with a "MyCustomLabel" label:

- Thunderbird:  "MyAccount/path/on/local/machine/MyCustomLabel"
- G-Mail: "MyCustomLabel"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Gmail now has nested labels.